# Problem with z-index

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, inline-styles

I must be missing something about z-index. Look at this code:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = '<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px' +
    '#000000; opacity: 0.7; display: block; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; ' +
    'left: 0px; right: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 1;"></div>';

span.innerHTML += '<div id="fancybox-wrap" style="opacity: 1; ' +
    'width: 420px; height: 200px; top: 467px; left: 481.5px; ' +
    'display: block; z-index: 2; ' +
    'border: 1px solid black;">Inside div</div>';
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Based on the fact that the second div has a higher z-index, should it be on top of the first div?

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qwertymk/TQSkX/ to see what I mean

Comment: You can't put a div inside a span.

Comment: Changing it to a div, didn't change anything. http://jsfiddle.net/qwertymk/TQSkX/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`z-index` does not apply to elements that are `position: static` (which is the default)

Comment: Awesome. Changed it to position: relative and worked like a charm. http://jsfiddle.net/qwertymk/TQSkX/7/ Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the position on the second div in the css for it to read the z-index.

add `position: relative;` to your second div and it should work fine.

```
   var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = '<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px' +
        '#000000; opacity: 0.7; display: block; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; ' +
        'left: 0px; right: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 1;"></div>';

    span.innerHTML += '<div id="fancybox-wrap" style="opacity: 1; ' + 
        'width: 420px; height: 200px; top: 467px; left: 481.5px; ' +
        'display: block; position: relative; z-index: 2; ' +
        'border: 1px solid black;">Inside div</div>';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
```